# Sideways figure at beginning of chapter

Tags: rotating, sidewaysfigure

In the thesis I'm writing, I have an appendix chapter with figures inserted sideways so they got ampliated. However, the first page in that chapter always stays blank, first picture moves to next page and (depending on configuration) may give aligneation problems.

The code I have for that is simple with nothing between the chapter header and the figure:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish, nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{Figura}{Figuras}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[babel,spanish=spanish]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\captionsetup[figure]{
    textformat = period, 
    labelsep = newline, 
    singlelinecheck = false, 
    font = {onehalfspacing}, 
    labelfont = bf,
    textfont = it, 
    position = above, 
    skip = 6pt,
}


\begin{document}

\appendix

\chapter{Figuras ampliadas del Capítulo 2.}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering %Without this, it prints weird figure-caption alignment.
    \captionsetup{width = 0.55\textwidth}
    \caption[Libro de texto de Edebé - Estructura de contenido.]{Estructura de contenido del libro de texto de Edebé (Fuente: Edebé, \citefield{Edebe2022}{year})}
    \label{fig:EdebeEstructuraAmp}
    \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{Edebe - Estructura}
\end{sidewaysfigure}


\end{document}
```

That makes that output. It's clear that is not an size issue, but don't know how to place it there
[image]
[image]

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rotating` package will use a full page to accommodate the rotated image and its caption.

A better solution is obtained with the `adjustbox` package.

The example adds a minipage of the correct width, with the caption, above the image and rotates the whole.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish, nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{Figura}{Figuras}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{rotating}

%\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[babel,spanish=spanish]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\captionsetup[figure]{
    textformat = period, 
    labelsep = newline, 
    singlelinecheck = false, 
    font = {onehalfspacing}, 
    labelfont = bf,
    textfont = it, 
    position = above, 
    skip = 6pt,
}
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \appendix
    
    \chapter{Figuras ampliadas del Capítulo 2.}
    
    \begin{figure}[ht]  
        \begin{adjustbox}{%
                addcode={\begin{minipage}{\width}\caption[Libro de texto de Edebé - Estructura de contenido.]{%
                                            Estructura de contenido del libro de texto de Edebé (Fuente: Edebé)}
                        \label{fig:EdebeEstructuraAmp}}{\end{minipage}},%
                    rotate=90,center}
            \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{example-image}%
        \end{adjustbox}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

An identical result can be obtained using the `hvfloat` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish, nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{Figura}{Figuras}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{rotating}
    
%\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[babel,spanish=spanish]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\usepackage{hvfloat}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \appendix
    
    \chapter{Figuras ampliadas del Capítulo 2.}     

    \hvFloat[floatPos=ht,
        objectAngle=90,
        capWidth=h,
        capPos=left,
        capAngle=90,
        capFormat={textformat = period, 
            labelsep = newline, 
            singlelinecheck = false, 
            font = {onehalfspacing}, 
            labelfont = bf,
            textfont = it, 
            skip = 6pt,},
        ]% 
        {figure}%
        {\includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{example-image}}%
        [Libro de texto de Edebé - Estructura de contenido.]{Estructura de contenido del libro de texto de Edebé (Fuente: Edebé)}{fig:EdebeEstructuraAmp}

\end{document}
```

I think a better alternative is to place the caption horizontally for better reading. This allows you to further enlarge the image and center all content in the text area.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish, nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{Figura}{Figuras}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{rotating}  

%\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[babel,spanish=spanish]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption} 

\usepackage{hvfloat}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{document}
    
    \appendix
    
    \chapter{Figuras ampliadas del Capítulo 2.}     

    \hvFloat[floatPos=ht,
        objectAngle=90, % rotate the image 90 dgr
        capWidth=w, % caption width = rotated image width
        capPos=top,
        capFormat={textformat = period, 
            labelsep = newline, 
            singlelinecheck = false, 
            font = {onehalfspacing}, 
            labelfont = bf,
            textfont = it, 
            skip = 6pt}, 
    ]% 
    {figure}%
    {\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image}}% wider image
    [Libro de texto de Edebé - Estructura de contenido.]{Estructura de contenido del libro de texto de Edebé (Fuente: Edebé)}{fig:EdebeEstructuraAmp}
    
\end{document}
```

The default caption position is at the bottom of the image. If so desired, use `skip=24pt` or similar.

Comment: This would look nicer with the figure centered horizontally.  This could be approximated by adding some blank space "under" the image, if other tactics don't work.

Comment: Such a clear explanation, Great

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563326/section-header-and-rotated-table-on-same-page/563330?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C24.3495#563330  The trick is to specify the height of the minipage as `\textwidth`.